# Link Share Problem to Facebook and Linkedin?

Tags: html, facebook, linkedin-api, linkshare

when i try to share  a link my website over like facebook or linkedin i got "403 Forbidden" error. May anyone help?
Here my link which is to share on facebook:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://dimguide.com/orfis-demo-font/
and linkedin :
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://dimguide.com/orfis-demo-font/&title=&summary=Bla Bla Bla&source=

and here my meta tags :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="preview.jpg">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="dimguide"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="bla bla bla"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://dimguide.com/orfis-demo-font/"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="dimguide"/>
    <style type="text/css" title="Default">
```

even though i can access "preview.jpg" without problem.
And all file permission is adjusted.

Comment: why isn't your first meta tag closed?

Comment: still same nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found problem. cause of mod security facebook and/or other site cant access data of my own site.